# Solution of $\frac{d}{dt}(a+bi) = if(t)(a+bi)$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Is it mathematically correct to say that 
$$\frac{d}{dt}(a+bi) = if(t)(a+bi)$$
implies that
$$(a+bi) = Ne^{ig(t)}$$
where $N$ is a complex constant and $\frac{d}{dt}{g}=\frac{f}{N}$?

I'm just not sure whether the reasoning is sound because of the complex nature of the functions

Comment: Actually, $z'(t)=if(t)z(t)$ is equivalent to $z(t)=Ce^{ig(t)}$ where $C$ is any complex constant and $g'(t)=f(t)$, not $g'(t)=f(t)/C$ as you wrote.

Comment: Oh, right cause $N=e^{iK}$ for some $K$ and then you have $e^{i(g(t) + K)}$.

Comment: @JanEerland Offtopic. Everybody understood that $a$ and $b$ are functions of $t$.